# Sim City 4 (Wine) crashes on Key Press, not sure why?

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

This might not be the place to ask this but it seems more related to Ubuntu than Wine or Sim City.

I've successfully played 6 hours of Sim City 4 on PlayOnLinux using Wine 1.7.9 through Steam. But I started it up today and each and every time I press a key the game crashes out.

I just deleted the disk and reinstalled it and the same thing, all I have to do it press Esc and it dies!

Any ideas how to trouble shoot, running it in debug didn't tell me much?

Thanks,
Noki

Comment: Problem has persisted after a system re-install. I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed** under Steam version by disabling the in-game overlay thusly: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3168263

This was disguised by the fact that my CD copy became broken, though it would install it would crash frequently. I purchased a Steam copy and the crash persisted, I recently figured out this was why.